# How do I update Object with Spring Data and MongoDB?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

How do I update Object with Spring Data and MongoDB?

do I just do a template.save()?

```
  public Person update( String id, String Name ) 
    {
        logger.debug("Retrieving an existing person");
        // Find an entry where pid matches the id

        Query query = new Query(where("pid").is(id));
        // Execute the query and find one matching entry
        Person person = mongoTemplate.findOne("mycollection", query, Person.class);

        person.setName(name);
        /**
        * How do I update the database
        */

        return person;
    }
```

Answer (score 13):

If you read the [javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoOperations.html#save%28java.lang.Object%29) for MongoOperations/MongoTemplate you will see that

```
save()
```

performs an:

```
upsert()
```

So yes you can just update your object and call save.

Comment: Keep in mind save() will override your whole object , while you maybe interested to update only part of the document.

Answer (score 7):

You could probably do both 'find' and 'update' operations in one line.

```
mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query,Update.update("Name", name),Person.class)
```

You can find some excellent tutorials at 
[Spring Data MongoDB Helloworld](http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/spring-data-mongodb-hello-world-example/)

Answer (score 5):

You can just use `template.save()` or `repository.save(entity)` methods for this. But mongo has also `Update` object for this operations.

For example:

```
Update update=new Update();
update.set("fieldName",value);
mongoTemplate.update**(query,update,entityClass);
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code is the equivalent implementation using MongoTemplate for update operation.

```
public Person update(Person person){
        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("id").is(person.getId()));
        Update update = new Update();
        update.set("name", person.getName());
        update.set("description", person.getDescription());
        return mongoTemplate.findAndModify(query, update, Person.class);
    }
```

Comment: I've also seen `Criteria.where("_id")` used. Could you comment? E.g. are both variants functional? Thanks!

Comment: _id field is primary key for every document and is also accessible via id.We can consider id as alias of _id.